# Clearing room DB when inside library module. Room cannot verify the data integrity

Tags: android, android-room

When testing a room database that's defined inside an Android Library module, and changing the database properties I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
```

However clearing data and uninstalling doesn't work. I can only assume that is because it's inside a different module to the app. 
I don't want to change the version number because this hasn't been released at all yet.

Comment: If you changed schema then you must update version

Comment: For me, it sometimes happens that the backup of the app information made automatically by the system gets in the way of clearing the app data. Try setting `android:allowBackup="false"` in your manifest and then install the app, clear the data and uninstall the app again.

Comment: allowBackup is already set to false.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the properties, then you also need to incement the *version* of the database, try this, if you made a change:

```
@Database(entities = {Coin.class}, version = 6, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class CoinDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract CoinDao daoAccess();
}
```

On the other hand, you can add an extra parameter when you build the database (in my case the repository constructor builds the db). The interesting part there is the *fallbackToDestructiveMigration()* , because the Room does not have "alter" or something you might use in relational databases, should use migration instead.

```
public CoinRepository(Context context) {
        coinDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, CoinDatabase.class, DB_NAME).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to increment the version as it's not live yet. Why would the first version of something not be 1 or lower?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was that you had to uninstall the test apk that is installed when running the espresso tests, and subsequently isn't uninstalled when just uninstalling your app.

When running gradle task `./gradlew uninstallAll` you can see it uninstalling the test package `Uninstalling com.example.roomexample.test` Then everything is fine.